# stateless function component+prop-types in react+typescript receiving a component as prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am converting a react only app into typescript, I am new to it.So this is a higher order component in react+typescript, i want to use prop-types with it, code:

```
interface GuestRouteProps {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  component: new (props: any) => React.Component; // is this right?
}

const GuestRoute: React.SFC<GuestRouteProps> = ({ // error on GuestRoute
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/' />
    }
  />
);
GuestRoute.propTypes = { // <-- the error is underlined here, works if no typescript
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

I get error that states 'Types of property 'component' are incompatible.'

Comment: I think the problem is the `new` on `component: new ...`. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: hello, i tried it, not working

Comment: The error is the same or it changes? Because I tested it locally in my project and if I remove the `new` it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: it doesn't work, adding propTypes messes it all. I want to have proptypes in it

Comment: Try removing the `new` keyword from the GuestRouteProps interface.

```tsx
interface GuestRouteProps {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  component: (props: any) => React.Component;
}
```